# Laravel cashier append and update migration

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using laravel cashier and stripe for checkout and subscription. I utilized the stripe's `redirectToBillingPortal()` method that lets me redirect to their site to manage my subscription, payment methods and other stuff. The problem is when I do a successful subscription, laravel cashier's default migrations `subscription_items` and `subscriptions` table doesn't append or add any data. Do I need something to add to stripe or that is how the way it works when I use the billing portal and not using cashier's methods? Or is it possible using stripe webhooks?

Comment: Please keep in mind that I haven't used Stripe and Cashier. But seems to me that you can define a `return_url` in the billing portal for the customers when they want to return to your website. [Docs here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/session). Also seems you are able to create webhooks for some events, perhaps you can utilize those to get the new data and insert in the database. [Docs here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks). Keep in mind this is just from reading a bit of docs, I've no experience just trying to help.